# mvn opposite of dependency:get? How to set up authorization?

Tags: maven

I've been tasked with writing scripts to interact with Nexus/Maven.  The files I'm working with in Maven are XML files placed there with the specific idea that they would be used by shell scripts.  Essentially, the files are configurations for another application.

I've already completed the scripts to pull the files from the repositories, but I'm having problems with putting files into the repositories.  To pull the files, I'm using the plugin dependency:get.

What I need is more or less the opposite of that plugin.  One that will update the repository with new versions of a file.  I think that "mvn deploy:deploy-file" is what I need to use.  Will that work?

If so, then the next problem I have is that I can't seem to figure out how to set up the authorization.  I have a settings file with a server defined that has the correct authorization information in it, but the link between the server and the repository (or URL?) is missing and the authorization isn't being performed correctly.

How do I connect the repository URL to the server info in the settings.xml file so that mvn will be authorized to perform the correct actions? (I don't know where the .pom file is for Maven, and may not have permissions to alter it.)

Thanks,

Sean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be in the -Durl option.

When using the dependency:get plugin, the URL was something like:

```
-Durl=http://companymavenrepo
```

And that worked fine for the dependency plugin.

However, that's not sufficient when trying to put things into the repository using the deploy plugin. The URL has to contain the maven server and the exact repository of where to place the artifact.  (My terminology might be off.)  I went to our Nexus/Sonatype webpage, looked at the exact repository where the artifact was stored, then used something like this:

```
-Durl=http://companymavenrepo/nexus/content/repositories/this_maven_repo
```

That solved the authorization problem, and I was able to add the file into the repository without issue.

(This might have been easier for other to see had I posted both mvn command lines I was trying to use.  On the other hand, it also seems reasonable that when you use the -Durl option with a specific value in one command line and it works that it will work unchanged in another command line.)

Sean.

Answer (score 0):

`deploy:deploy-file` is correct. Use it with `-Durl=http://repo:port/path`, `-DrepositoryId=server-whatever`. Your `settings.xml` needs to contain

```
 <servers>
    <server>
      <id>server-whatever</id>
      <username>demo</username>
      <password>demo</password>
    </server>
  </servers>
```

where the server ID `server-whatever` matches the `repositoryId` parameter.

Having said that, I'd question the appropriateness of Maven for this. It's designed for binary artifaccts rather than configuration.

Comment: The bad news is that I had all that beforehand.  Here's my mvn call:mvn -s <path-to>/settings.xml deploy:deploy-file -Durl=http://mymavenrepo/ -DrepositoryId=myrepoid -DgroupId=groud-id -DartifactId=filename.xml -Dversion=1.0.2 -Dpackaging=xml -Dfile=filename.xml.

Comment: My server section is almost as you suggested, with the repositoryId being the same as the one defined in the command line.  The differences in the server section are the additions of 'filepermissions' and 'directorypermissions'.  Yet I'm still getting an auth error.  Any ideas?

Comment: Can you use Wireshark to sniff the HTTP traffic?

Comment: I have a feeling if I tried to sniff network traffic here security would be all over me.  While I might be able to get away with it, I really don't want to take a chance.  Sniffing the network is the kind of thing that can get contractors fired...

Comment: Could it be a version problem?  In using the dependency:get plugin, I had a problem that was solved when I used a later version of the plugin.

Comment: Well, if Wireshark is too cyberpunk, you could try something cuddlier like Fiddler, and direct Maven through that by setting it to use a localhost proxy. Try the latest version of the plugin but I doubt that's the problem.

Comment: Does the user you're specifying have permissions to deploy to your remote repo?  You may be getting the auth error not because the credentials are wrong, but because the user doesn't have write perms to the repo.